# Count number of rows from specific row below

Tags: mysql

This is my table

[image]

How can I write query where I want to select number of rows starting from ID=2 (or it could be any other number I enter) but only where IDveterinar=5 or some other number I enter

Somethink like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM mytable...`

Comment: guy below have answered my question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the number of row starting from ID 2 (included) this is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE ID >= 2 AND IDveterinar = 5;
```

If you want to select the number of row starting from ID 2 (excluded) this is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE ID > 2 AND IDveterinar = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count FROM mytable
WHERE 
    ID >= 2
    AND IDveterinar = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM mytable WHERE id>=2 AND IDveterinar=5;
```